Почему выдает ошибку при работе с прокси и телеграм аккаунтом в telethon
Привте! Есть код:
from telethon import TelegramClient


api_id = 123456  
api_hash = 'your_api_hash' 
session_file = 'ac1.session' 

proxy = ('45.89.19.62', 16141) 
proxy_config = {
    'proxy_type': 'socks5', 
    'addr': proxy[0],  # Адрес прокси
    'port': proxy[1],  # Порт прокси
    'username': 'login',  # Если требуется, добавьте логин
    'password': 'password'  # Если требуется, добавьте пароль
}

client = TelegramClient(session_file, api_id, api_hash, proxy=proxy_config)

async def main():
    try:
        await client.start()
        print("Успешно подключено!")

        me = await client.get_me()
        print(f"Вы вошли как {me.first_name} ({me.username})")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Ошибка: {e}")

    finally:
        await client.disconnect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import asyncio
    asyncio.run(main())

и при запуске ошибка:
Attempt 1 at connecting failed: GeneralProxyError: Socket error: 0x02: Connection not allowed by ruleset
Дело точно не в прокси т.к там все правильно!

Продиагностировать проблему можно командой traceroute -T 45.89.19.62 -p 16141

сервер отклонил запрос на подключение, либо логин/пароль неправильный, либо есть ограничение порта в настройках сервера.
серверов прокси много, с другими не пробовали или нужно именно к этому прокси подключиться?

это вопрос или ответ?

ответ, по выданной сервером ошибке.

@arcadiybochkov Смотрите я даже пробоавал другой сервер, но там тоже ошибка!
